How to take out common utility in a single codebase when adopting to microservice
Consider I have 2 microservices , now I have a situation where I have written a error handling function wrapping all my contollers of one of the services (more or less this function is creating a log in my kakfa and sending the response to my client in a specified signature). Now same thing I want to have in my other service and I do not want to write that code again (duplicate them).
So my question is how do we handle such a scenarios when opting for microservices. (I feel whatever we do to tackle this should be tech stack agnostic).
One approach that comes to my mind is make them a module but making it a complete module and sharing through npm registry seems a over kill to me.

Making a complete module doesn't mean you have to sharing it through npm registry, package.json can accept local path or git repo url.

but is the way we do it in production ready apps or is there is any alternative to that?

If you want to share code in proper production scale, you may take a look at monorepo
